# Calling the value of an array in subroutine

Tags: random, numbers, fortran, fortran77

I am using Force 2.0 compiler and editor. I want to call the value of the existing array `KM(1:M)` on the following subroutine to be used in the calculation in the main program `EIKM(1:M)`, but the values obtained are not in accordance with the value of the array. Can you tell me what is wrong and what should I do?

```
  PROGRAM GENERATES_EIKM

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER I, M, N
  PARAMETER (M=65, N=3)
  REAL EIKM(1:M)

  REAL ALFA, EPSILON, NU, PI
  REAL U2RMS, KE, KEFISIENSI, KALI, KALE
  REAL KM(1:M), LS

  REAL KMLOW, KMHIGH, DELTAKM

  KMLOW=100
  KMHIGH = 10000
  DELTAKM = (KMHIGH-KMLOW)/(M-1)

  PI = 3.14
  ALFA = 1.453
  EPSILON = 10
  NU = 7
  LS = 23
  KE = ALFA*9*PI/(55*LS)
  KEFISIENSI = (EPSILON**(1/4))/(NU**(-3/4))


  CALL CALLING_THE_VALUE_OF_KM (M)

  WRITE (*,*) 'CHECKING THE VALUE OF KM AT DATA NUMBER 2 : ', KM(2)

  DO I=1,M
     U2RMS = (2/3*KM(I))**2
     KALI = KM(I)/KE
     KALE = KM(I)/KEFISIENSI
     EIKM(I) = ALFA*(U2RMS/KE)*((KALI**4)/((1+KALI**2)**(17/6)))*
 &           EXP(-2*(KALE**2))
     WRITE (*,*) 'THE VALUE OF EIKM AT (I) ', I, EIKM(I)
  END DO

  PAUSE
  END



  SUBROUTINE CALLING_THE_VALUE_OF_KM (M)

  REAL KM(1:M)
  INTEGER I
  REAL KMLOW, KMHIGH, DELTAKM
  KMLOW=100
  KMHIGH = 10000
  DELTAKM = (KMHIGH-KMLOW)/(M-1)

  WRITE(*,*) 'START OF CALLING_THE_VALUE_OF_KM'
  DO I=1,M
     KM(I) = KMLOW + DELTAKM*(I-1)
     WRITE(*,*) I, KM(I)
  END DO
  WRITE(*,*) 'END OF CALLING_THE_VALUE_OF_KM'
  WRITE(*,*) '--------------------'

  RETURN
  END
```

Comment: Move the `end` which matches the program statement to the end of the source file.  In its place write the word `contains`.  Recompile and fix any errors that the compiler finds.  As your code is structured the compiler can't ensure that the argument passed to the subroutine matches what is expected.

Comment: Furthermore, a beginner in 2016 should not be learning Fortran 77, there are many useful features which have been added to the language in the more recent versions and it simply doesn't make sense to confine yourself to a 40-year old version of the language.  Yes, you still need to know Fortran 77 for integration with the enormous existing codebase, but no, you don't need to confine yourself to writing it.  It's funny, but I never see questions on SO that start *I'm learning Java 2 ...*

Comment: Somebody somewhere seems to still be teaching people F77...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark i am using fortran 77 language, and in my compiler there is not implicit funtion like 'contains' .This is my first time to make such a program to solve an equation, my supervisor told me to use fortran77 because it can be run in any computer. Please help me Master!!

Comment: You need to start debugging, and those integer/integer may be better as 2.0/3.0 and 1.0+Kali and 17.0/6.0 and -2.0 * probably easiest to say "real PARAMETER :: factor1 = 2.0/3.0" etc . All that stuff that @HighPerformanceMark mentioned are part of a sage approach.

Comment: *i am using fortran 77*  Not if you write `implicit none` you're not.  Strictly speaking that wasn't added until the 90 edition of the language

Answer (score 1):

I would put IMPLICIT NONE in your subroutine. If M is defined as an integer or not then that would help. You could also put INTENT(IN) on M and see if the compiler also does fortran90. If the subroutine is supposed to output something then you will need that inside the (). You proby want...:

F90:

```
Subroutine Callingthevalue_of_KM(M, KM)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER            , INTENT(IN   ) :: M
REAL, DIMENSION (M), INTENT(INOUT) :: kM
```

If that compiles then it must be force 2.0.9+
And then you probably do not need M

```
Subroutine Callingthevalue_of_KM(KM)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION (:), INTENT(INOUT) :: kM
INTEGER                            :: M

M = Size(kM)
... Or do the loops a DO I = 1, SIZE(kM)
```

F77:

```
Subroutine Callingthevalue_of_KM(M, KM)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER   M
REAL      kM(M)
```

In all those cases km will be "returned" via the reference for km, with updates values on km then known by the main.

The other way for kM to be known inside and outside is a COMMON, but I believe it is conceptually easier to shy away from them at this point.

Comment: For the assumed-shape version, more substantial changes (explicit interface provision) are required than just adding `(:)`.

Comment: @Holmz it is not working. For example, the answerr of calling data number 2 is still 0.000 . Please help me master!

Comment: Try this after the call to the subroutine and see what you get....

WRITE (*,*) 'CHECKING THE VALUE OF KM AT DATA NUMBER (1:5) : ', KM(1:5)

Doing it inside the subroutine would also be worthwhile.